Adding a new item to a list in Ansible
I have an array
  a1:
    - channelId: test1
    - channelId: test2

I'm trying to add a new key-pair value to the array
  a2:
    - channelId: test1
    - channelId: test2
    - channelId: test3



Ansible Playbook : Part of the code where I'm trying to add the new key value pair to the existing JSON array
- name: Setting Channel id
  set_fact:
    channelarray: "{{ newrelic_alertpolicyresult | json_query('json.data.actor.account.aiWorkflows.workflows.entities[*].destinationConfigurations[*]')}}"
    workflowid: "{{ newrelic_alertpolicyresult | json_query('json.data.actor.account.aiWorkflows.workflows.entities[*].id') }}"
    
- name: PrintChannel ID
  debug:
    msg: "Channel ID - {{ channelarray }}  &  Workflow ID - {{ workflowid }}"
    
- name: PrintChannel ID in loop
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ channelarray }}"

- name: Convert JSON to dictionary
  set_fact: 
    updated_channel_array: "{{ channelarray + [{ 'channelId': 'test3' }] | json_query('[*]')  }}"

  
- name: Print updated channel array
  debug:
     msg: "{{ updated_channel_array }}"

Output :
TASK [Setting Channel id] 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [PrintChannel ID] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Channel ID - [[{'channelId': 'f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01'}, {'channelId': 'be33c326-08d4-494c-b544-6c86beb0dd5e'}]]  &  Workflow ID - ['d7d1db30-918e-4202-a7ba-1613cf9600a1']"
}

TASK [PrintChannel ID in loop] 
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'channelId': 'f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01'}, {'channelId': 'be33c326-08d4-494c-b544-6c86beb0dd5e'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "channelId": "f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01"
        },
        {
            "channelId": "be33c326-08d4-494c-b544-6c86beb0dd5e"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Convert JSON to dictionary] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "channelId": "f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01"
            },
            {
                "channelId": "be33c326-08d4-494c-b544-6c86beb0dd5e"
            }
        ],
        {
            "channelId": "test3"
        }
    ]
}


Last Key pair value should be added to the destinationConfigurations array


Can you please post the ansible playbook you are using.

The below expression
  a2: "{{ a1 + [{ 'channelId': 'test3' }] }}"

gives what you want
  a2:
  - channelId: test1
  - channelId: test2
  - channelId: test3

Use set_fact if you want to update an array
    - set_fact:
        a1: "{{ a1 + [{ 'channelId': 'test3' }] }}"

gives what you want
  a1:
  - channelId: test1
  - channelId: test2
  - channelId: test3



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    a1:
      - channelId: test1
      - channelId: test2

    a2: "{{ a1 + [{ 'channelId': 'test3' }] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: a2

    - set_fact:
        a1: "{{ a1 + [{ 'channelId': 'test3' }] }}"
    - debug:
        var: a1


